# From Silverlight to MVC CslaModelBinding child collections

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, csla

Background:

A while ago we developed a business application for silverlight using the csla framework. Now we wish to create an MVC alternative for people who are unable to use Silverlight for one reason or another.

The problem:

Now the problem is that we wish to re-use the  existing business library for the MVC application. We wish to save a parent and all its children as a batch but the cslamodelbinder does not bind the child objects. Is there a way of binding these child collections?

If not, and we have to save each child seperate as though it were a parent what would be the easiest way? (Bearing in mind all the child objects only have Child data portal methods)

I've tried looking around forums and have only managed to find a very small handfull of posts regarding this problem and these were a little old, was wondering if anyone has found a good solution since then?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

To close the loop on this question, your thread in the CSLA forums seems to provide answers:

http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/t/10770.aspx